# null pointer exception in selenium code using java

Tags: java, javascript, css, string, selenium

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class RedBus {
    Selenium selenium;

    @BeforeClass
    public void base()
    {
    Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.redbus.in");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowMaximize();
    selenium.open("/"); 
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
    }       

    @Test
    public void domain() throws InterruptedException
    {           
            selenium.type("//input[@id='DDLSource']","hyde");
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
        if(selenium.isTextPresent("//dt[@value='Hyderabad']"))
        {
            selenium.click("//dt[@value='Hyderabad']");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ele not found");
        }
    /*  
        selenium.type("//input[@id='DDLDestination']","pune");

        selenium.click("//img[@alt='Select your date of journey']");
        */



    }

}
```

Comment: Describe your problem and include the details of the exception, please.

Comment: please post your Stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not apparent where you're getting a `NullPointerException`, I suspect that you need to change the following line:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.redbus.in");
```

to

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.redbus.in");
```

At present you're initialising a new `Selenium` object in your setup method that is only in scope in your `base` method, rather than your class-level `Selenium` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You defined class field `Selenium selenium;` that is not initialized and therefore is `null`. Then in `base()` method you created *another local* variable `Selenium selenium` and initialized it. Then int your test you try to use selenium field that is not initialized.

To make your code to work remove `Selenium` from line `Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium...`, i.e.:

```
@BeforeClass
public void base() {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost",4444,"*firefox","http://www.redbus.in");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowMaximize();
    selenium.open("/"); 
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("10000");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

DefaultSelenium selenium=null;

// use this instead of Selenium selenium;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "http://www.redbus.in");

// no need to use selenium.start(); or set a default port

// the following line
  `selenium.type` .. will still return a null pointer if you are using firefox 35 or above. so first try in `firefox 15` and then check on `firefox 34` and Please do not take any firefox updates after you install 34.

I have used the following jars

selenium-server-coreless-1.0-20081010.060147.jar
selenium-java-2.44.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar

//Import statements

```
 import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
   import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
```

Regards,
Ravinath Edirisinghe